# What constitutes "About Me" for the autobiographer badge?

Tags: support, badges, meta

I have filled in a few lines on the about me page but my profile still is suggesting me to go and get my autobiographer badge.

Is their a minimum line count or additional information required in user profile? (I have updated my profile picture too).

Comment: Awarding of badges takes some time. Be patient ... if it didn't get awarded after 24 hours it is time to expect some scripts didn't run.

Comment: That makes sense. Is my understanding of the award rules fine then?

Comment: The question I linked as dupe is maybe different but the answer qualifies as an aswer for your question as well